# FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread when using Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I can't get the title of Google's homepage with Jsoup. I'm getting `FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread`.

Logcat:

```
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-75
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:3939)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:701)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6716)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3256)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3110)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3085)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.example.spravochnik05.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:34)
10-19 05:46:44.153: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textView;
    public Document doc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();
                    textView.setText(doc.title());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

New error logcat:

```
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spravochnik05/com.example.spravochnik05.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:425)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.example.spravochnik05.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-19 06:08:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  ... 11 more
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textView.setText(doc.title());
```

Remove this line. You cannot update the UI from a thread. Instead use `runOnUIThread()`, or use a handler for thread.

The best option is to use `AsyncTask` , which is recommended by Android.

Below is usage of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which performs background operations in the `doInBackground() method` and updates the UI in the `onPostExecute` method.

Here's an example of using an `AsyncTask`:

In your `onCreate` method:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute();
```

And after `onCreate` ends add this class:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (doc != null) {
                textView.setText(doc.title());
            }
            else {
                textView.setText("Doc not found");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: can i to execute this code more time? i want to execute after click on button

Comment: @СулейманДибиров are you looking for parallel execution or looping something in background. if so use a thread with looper . for paralle execution use a executor

Comment: new DownloadFilesTask().execute(); use this as many times as you want :)

Answer (score 2):

as in log:

> CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created
>   a view hierarchy can touch its views.

means you are trying to update UI elements from non-ui Thread so use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for update UI elements from non ui Thread.

using `runOnUiThread` :

```
 .....
 try {
         doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();
         MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
            public void run() {
                 textView.setText(doc.title());
             }
          });           
        } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

......

Comment: please share new logcat results to get more help and also add null check for doc.title() value before passing it to setText method

Answer (score 0):

You can't change text of `TextView` in non UI Thread. try to use `runOnUIThread(Runnable)` method in `Activity` in non UI Threads for communicating with UI Thread

Answer (score 0):

Use an [**AyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of threads, because this line:

```
textView.setText(doc.title());
```

will give you an error as you are getting right now.

Answer (score 0):

Take the code from your thread, and put it in an AsyncTask thread:

```
class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                your code
    }

}
```

Certain actions, such as making HTTP requests, are not allowed to run on the main UI thread.

To execute:

```
new DownloadFile().execute()
```